# when we solve the simple ODE then

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, code-request

```
NDSolve[{u'[y] + (k + y) u''[y] - Ha^2 (k + y) u[y] - 
    u[y]/(-k + y) == -k, u[-1] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u[y], y]
```

gives the error

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at y == -1..
```

Comment: You are using `NDSolve` but several parameters are left arbitrary

Comment: sir i cannot understand

Comment: You have not defined specific values for `k` etc

Answer (score 1):

Being new, you should be aware built-in Mathematica functions and commands begin with upper-case letters including the single-letter commands:  C,D, E, I, K,N O.  If you were to begin a user-defined variable with an upper-case letter, it could conflict with built-in commands.  Best then to always start user-defined variables with a lower-case letter.  Need also to assign values to  constants in equation to numerically integrate it.  It's also simpler in my opinion to use `NDSolveValue` which returns the function directly.  Here's a test case:

```
Ha = 1.5;
k = 2.3;
theSol = 
 NDSolveValue[{u'[y] + (k + y) u''[y] - Ha^2 (k + y) u[y] - 
     u[y]/(-k + y) == -k, u[-1] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u, y]
Plot[theSol[y], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]